# Python - is it possible to use pandas .pipe() to add a new column that has 2 level of column header?

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with a multi-index dataframe because I've used pd.pivot_table. There are two levels in my column header.

I am currently processing it and would like to sum two columns together.

I would like to make my code cleaner by processing the df in one chain using .pipe()

What I have come up with is this:

```
reg_cat = 
    1 or 0  total_orders  year
    0       1          2000  2011
    1       0          5500  2012
    2       1          6000  2013
    3       0          1000  2014
    4       0          3000  2015

pivot = (
  reg_cat
  .pivot_table(values=['total_orders'],index=['year'],columns=['1 or 0'], aggfunc=np.sum)
  .reset_index()
  .fillna(0)
  .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(total_orders_total = x['total_orders',0] + x['total_orders',1]))
)
```

The output is presented as such:

```
        year total_orders total_orders total_orders_total
1 or 0                  0            1                   
0       2011          0.0       2000.0             2000.0
1       2012       5500.0          0.0             5500.0
2       2013          0.0       6000.0             6000.0
3       2014       1000.0          0.0             1000.0
4       2015       3000.0          0.0             3000.0
```

How can I insert a 2nd level column name for the column 'total_orders_total' with this method? So that it will look something like this:

```
        year total_orders total_orders total_orders_total
1 or 0                  0            1              total
0       2011          0.0       2000.0             2000.0
1       2012       5500.0          0.0             5500.0
2       2013          0.0       6000.0             6000.0
3       2014       1000.0          0.0             1000.0
4       2015       3000.0          0.0             3000.0
```

Comment: Can you add sample data of `reg_cat` ?

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope this is clearer. @jezrael

Comment: I try some solutions and all failed, not sure if this is implemented in pandas. problem is how use assign for multiindex in columns.